# unable to install ScnSocialAuth-is not available in a stable-enough version imum-stability setting

Tags: zend-framework2

i have two issues:

i am trying to install **ScnSocialAuth** via composer on my zend 2 project but get this error message:

```
Problem 1
    - socalnick/scn-social-auth 1.9.4 requires hybridauth/hybridauth dev-master                                                                                                                 -> no matching package found.
    - socalnick/scn-social-auth 1.5.1 requires zf-commons/zfc-base dev-master ->                                                                                                                 no matching package found.
    - socalnick/scn-social-auth 1.18.1 requires zf-commons/zfc-user 1.2.* -> no                                                                                                                 matching package found.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
```

this is my composer.json file:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user": "~0.1.2",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*",
        "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "0.*",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "slm/mail": "~1.5",
        "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "1.4.*",
        "acelaya/zf2-acmailer": "4.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*",
        "nikolaposa/zf-open-graph": "1.*",
        "socalnick/scn-social-auth": "1.*"
    }
```

i tried manually installing the package but then got this error message:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Hybrid_Auth' not found in \vendor\ScnSocialAuth\src\ScnSocialAuth\Service\HybridAuthFactory.php on line 34
```

so, i suspect that the package needs to be installed via  composer

would appreciate advise on how to properly install it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `@dev` version requirement for hybridauth in your composer.json, ie, make it look like this ...

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "zendframework/zendframework": "2.3.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user": "~0.1.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.*",
    "zf-commons/zfc-user-doctrine-orm": "0.*",
    "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
    "slm/mail": "~1.5",
    "bjyoungblood/bjy-authorize": "1.4.*",
    "acelaya/zf2-acmailer": "4.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "4.3.*",
    "nikolaposa/zf-open-graph": "1.*",
    "socalnick/scn-social-auth": "1.*",
    "hybridauth/hybridauth": "@dev"
}
```

Comment: hey Crisp. thank you for the advise. i will try it now. in the mean time, i wonder if you would look a this question here; basically, i just did a fresh project. i am now able to install the Scn. However it will not work becuase the zend session is missing; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33064272/an-alias-scnsocialauth-zendsessionmanager-was-requested-but-no-service-could-b