# An alias "ScnSocialAuth_ZendSessionManager" was requested but no service could be found

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to install **ScnSocialAuth_ZendSessionManager** into my zend 2 application. 
i am getting the following error message when i try to go to the login or registration page:

```
An alias "ScnSocialAuth_ZendSessionManager" was requested but no service could be found.
```

i have followed the instructions  [here:](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth)

and uploaded it.

i then install

```
./vendor/socalnick/scn-social-auth/config/scn-social-auth.global.php.dist
/vendor/socalnick/scn-social-auth/config/scn-social-auth.local.php.dist
```

to my config.

Then within the scn-social-auth.global.php i did the following:

```
$settings = array(

    'zend_db_adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',

    'zend_session_manager' => 'Zend\Session\SessionManager'
}
);

return array(
    'scn-social-auth' => $settings,
    'service_manager' => array(
        'aliases' => array(
            'ScnSocialAuth_ZendDbAdapter' => (isset($settings['zend_db_adapter'])) ? $settings['zend_db_adapter']: 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter',
            'ScnSocialAuth_ZendSessionManager' => (isset($settings['zend_session_manager'])) ? $settings['zend_session_manager']: 'Zend\Session\SessionManager',
        ),
    ),
);
```

i also created a ./config/autoload/session.local.php:

```
<?php

return array(
    'service_manager' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Zend\Session\SessionManager' => 'Zend\Session\SessionManager',
        ),
    ),
);
```

so, i am unclear why i am still getting the error message;

would really appriciate any advise on this.

UPDATE

i also added the module to composer:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.*",
        "socalnick/scn-social-auth": "1.*"
    }
```

UPATE 
Wilt has asked what values are returned when i var_dump the config values.
the returned values are:

```
  array (size=3)
          'ScnSocialAuth_ZendDbAdapter' => string 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' (length=23)
          'ScnSocialAuth_ZendSessionManager' => string 'Zend\Session\SessionManager' (length=27)
          'zfcuser_zend_db_adapter' => string 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' (length=23)
```

you will observe that the **ScnSocialAuth_ZendSessionManager** is aliasing the zend sesssion manager.

so, i am unclear why it say that the service cannot be found.

would really appriciate some advice on this.

Comment: add it to composer list, i guess this library/plugin can be found over google, and then update composer

Comment: hi boobie. i did add it to composer. so, could your clarfiy your adivse regarding finding the plugin and updating composer

Comment: Well if you added it to composer then google composer update command. After that file will be found , as its a library

Comment: hi. i tried it again and its still not working. do you have any idea noobie why its not working

Comment: Did you add the module to your `application.config.php`?

Comment: hi tim. i did indeed add it: 'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'ScnSocialAuth',
        'ZfcBase',
        'ZfcUser',
    ),

Answer (score 0):

You need the `scn-social-auth.global.php` and the `scn-social-auth.local.php` to you application config folder and set all the config parameters that are required.

In this file you find [the key `'ScnSocialAuth_ZendSessionManager'`](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth/blob/master/config/scn-social-auth.global.php.dist#L215). Your issue is probably related to some configuration problem related to these config files.

Since you said you loaded them I would says something is wrong with your autoload setup.

Does your ZF2 application have the [proper system configuration](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html):

```
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor',
    ),
    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{{,*.}global,{,*.}local}.php',
    )
)
```

Check once if your merged `$config` array contains all your keys?

```
$config = $serviceManager->get('Config');
```

Comment: hello wilt. i did what you asked. it seems to be returning the session so i am unclear what the problem is. i have enclosed what was shown. please look at my question edit

Comment: @PaulKendal What is returned for `'Zend\Session\SessionManager'`? The SessionManager class is not an invokable class. You have to [set it up using a factory](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.manager.html). I think the `'Zend\Session\SessionManager'` service is not available. try to make this: `$serviceManager->get('Zend\Session\SessionManager');` work first...